# How to add Admin Credentials in AWS Cognito SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

How to add Admin Credentials in AWS Cognito SDK

I am looking to use the AWS Cognito SDK on a backend Node.js server but can't find any documentation on how to pass the client secret in so that I can use admin commands for Cognito. Can someone provide some guidance for how I could accomplish this in SDK V3?

Comment: Not 100% sure I know what you're asking here, but if your back-end is running on AWS and needs to make AWS API requests to manage Cognito resources then configure the back-end with an IAM role that permits the relevant Cognito actions.

Comment: @jarmod Hey! I'm looking to use something like AdminDeleteUserCommand in the Cognito Identity Provider. Cognito has apps that have secrets that say they allow us to use admin commands (as compared to apps that don't have secrets that are meant to live on the front end), but none of the parameters on the AdminDeleteUserCommand indicate a place where I can pass in the secret.

Comment: The 'admin users' that you're referring to here are AWS developers or administrators. They have AWS credentials, not Cognito credentials. To use [AdminDeleteUserCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/admindeleteusercommand.html), supply AWS credentials to your backend app in the usual AWS way i.e. IAM roles.